# Colorbox width on links

Tags: javascript

I am using [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module through views to display some catalog nodes using colorbox. When someone clicks on a catalog link it opens in colorbox.

Now my client wants to display the link to the latest catalog in a splash screen whenever someone visits the website.

I have used [Splashify](https://www.drupal.org/project/splashify) module to display splash screen and entered the new catalog image with link to the relevant catalog node.

Problem is that the width of the colorbox is not changing accordingly. Means when someone clicks on the catalog image in a splash screen which is perfectly loaded in a colorbox, the colorbox loads the catalog node but the size of colorbox remains the same.

The link which I am using within colorbox is http://patelbrothers.com.pk/catalog/moonlight?width=1000&height=500&iframe=true